# Pandas, the searching is really hard?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Here I want to search the values of `paper_title` column in `reference` column if matched/found as whole text, get the `_id` of that reference row **(not `_id` of `paper_title` row)** where it matched and save the `_id` in the `paper_title_in` column.

```
In[1]:

d ={
  "_id":
    [
      "Y100",
      "Y100",
      "Y100",
      "Y101",
      "Y101",
      "Y101",
      "Y102",
      "Y102",
      "Y102"
    ]
  ,
  "paper_title":
    [
      "translation using information on dialogue participants",
      "translation using information on dialogue participants",
      "translation using information on dialogue participants",
      "#emotional tweets",
      "#emotional tweets",
      "#emotional tweets",
      "#supportthecause: identifying motivations to participate in online health campaigns",
      "#supportthecause: identifying motivations to participate in online health campaigns",
      "#supportthecause: identifying motivations to participate in online health campaigns"
    ]
  ,
  "reference":
    [
      "beattie, gs (2005, november) #supportthecause: identifying motivations to participate in online health campaigns may 31, 2017, from",
      "burton, n (2012, june 5) depressive realism retrieved may 31, 2017, from",
      "gotlib, i h, 27 hammen, c l (1992) #supportthecause: identifying motivations to participate in online health campaigns new york: wiley",
      "paul ekman 1992 an argument for basic emotions cognition and emotion, 6(3):169200",
      "saif m mohammad 2012a #tagspace: semantic embeddings from hashtags in mail and books to appear in decision support systems",
      "robert plutchik 1985 on emotion: the chickenand-egg problem revisited motivation and emotion, 9(2):197200",
      "alastair iain johnston, rawi abdelal, yoshiko herrera, and rose mcdermott, editors 2009 translation using information on dialogue participants cambridge university press",
      "j richard landis and gary g koch 1977 the measurement of observer agreement for categorical data biometrics, 33(1):159174",
      "tomas mikolov, kai chen, greg corrado, and jeffrey dean 2013  #emotional tweets arxiv:13013781"
    ]

}

import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(d)

df
```

Out:

[image: dataframe]

Expected Results:

[image: Expected Result]

> And finally the final result dataframe with unique values as:

Note here `paper_title_in` column has all the `_id` of title present in `reference` column as list.

[image: Final_dataframe]

I tried this but it returns the `_id` of `paper_title` column in `paper_presented_in` which is being searched than `reference` column where it matches. The expected result dataframe gives more clear idea. Have a look there.

```
def return_id(paper_title,reference, _id):
    if (paper_title is None) or (reference is None):
        return None
    if paper_title in reference:
        return _id
    else:
        return None

df1['paper_present_in'] = df1.apply(lambda row: return_id(row['paper_title'], row['reference'], row['_id']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

So to solve your problem you'll be requiring two dictionaries and a list to store some values temporarily.

```
# A list to store unique paper titles
unique_paper_title


# A dict to store mapping of unique paper to unique ids
mapping_dict_paper_to_id = dict()

# A dict to store mapping unique idx to the ids
mapping_id_to_idx = dict()


# This gives us the unique paper title's list
unique_paper_title = df["paper_title"].unique()



# Storing values in the dict mapping_dict_paper_to_id

for value in unique_paper_title:
    mapping_dict_paper_to_id[value] = df["_id"][df["paper_title"]==value].unique()[0]



# Storing values in the dict mapping_id_to_idx

for value in unique_paper_title:

    # this gives us the indexes of the matched string ie. the paper_title
    idx_list = df[df['reference'].str.contains(value)].index

    # Storing values in the dictionary
    for idx in idx_list:
        mapping_id_to_idx[idx] = mapping_dict_paper_to_id[value]


# This loops check if the index have any refernce's id and then updates the paper_present_in field accordingly

for i in df.index:
    if i in mapping_id_to_idx:
        df['paper_present_in'][i] = mapping_id_to_idx[i]
    else:
        df['paper_present_in'][i] = "None"
```

The above code is gonna check and update the searched values in the dataframe.

Comment: Have you tested this code in sample dataframe? I am trying but it isn't returning the final list as expected. Can you please look what is wrong?

Comment: I did tested it with the sample dataframe but the result that you want from your sample dataframe does not matches your requirement as after searching the paper_title in the references we get only 4 matches and you can see that they have updated the paper_present_in field. In your expected dataframe there should be a None value at the index  1 and some value at index 0 but it is just opposite of it. The logic is based on what you asked for ie. matching and then storing the "_id" at the "reference "s "paper_present_in" field.

Comment: Actually I wanted the final list mentioned above in question. you provided the half answer. See the second last part in block quotes.(yellow highlighted part)

Comment: You cannot get  the list by the doubt you have. Try to explain your problem more thoroughly if I'm understanding it wrong.

Comment: Edited the question and want the final dataframe as result.

Comment: Run the code on original dataframe of 900k rows and it took 20 min to finish it with throwing error: nothing to repeat at position 0 (in str.contains method) on 128GB RAM server. It would be great if  you could provide more efficient way of helping me. And please downvote the question as it gets less attraction to get answered. It would also be great if you share this with the person you know might help me by providing this question a fresh pair of eyes.